# Panorma Turtlebot

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with the turtlebot 3 when i am using the function

```
rosservice call turtlebot3_panorama/take_pano 0 360.0 30.0 0.3
```

i never get 360 degree pictures but rather 180 degree
Also when i select the panorama picture in `rqt_image_view` during the process of snapshot taking it seems to crash the process resulting in: at the end of panorama programm

```
[ INFO] [1528970263.286862092]: Stiching 12 images
[ INFO] [1528970269.967378861]: Finished Stiching
[ERROR] [1528970269.967413585]: Compressed Depth Image Transport - Compression requires single-channel 32bit-floating point or 16bit raw depth images (input format is: bgr8).
OpenCV Error: Unknown error code -10 (Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported)) in throwOnEror, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp, line 140
[ERROR] [1528970269.967481032]: /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.3.1/modules/imgcodecs/src/grfmt_base.cpp:140: error: (-10) Raw image encoder error: Empty JPEG image (DNL not supported) in function throwOnEror
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295020/panorma-turtlebot/) by [arminkazim](https://answers.ros.org/users/36033/arminkazim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2018-06-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've seen this same error writing a node in Python. The problem was that, before cv2.imencode(), one of the images was None (the NULL equivalent in Python). So check that your images are not NULL or 0xN or whatever alike. Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Avio](https://answers.ros.org/users/19863/avio/) with karma: 96 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1